# Measuring native mobile app response time without code injection

Tags: android, logcat, mobile-application, latency, response-time

I am trying to measure the response time for mobile applications. Apps are downloaded from the Google PlayStore, So I have no original source code for them. This makes we cannot inject some code for tracking the time like logcat etc. What I wanna know is that the response time for specific interactions (e.g. the time from clicking the item to loading all UIs).

My target apps are the native mobile apps, not a mobile web or hybrid version. Thus, the apps are neither using a javascript nor using onLoad event.

Is there any framework for measuring the native mobile app response time without code injection?
In addition, is there any method which tells us that the Android mobile app UI load is done like an onLoad event on web version?

Thanks for any info you can provide.

Comment: No there is no such event. Because there is no "UI load" concept in android.  There's activity creation, which may or may not cause a UI to be loaded.  And there's no hook for that either.

Comment: @GabeSechan, Then, how about tracking View classes using hooking tools like Frida(https://www.frida.re/)? After sending a request, wait for the end time of View classes. Do you think is it reasonable and deployable?